# pgfplots: loglogaxis dual axis tick transform

Tags: pgfplots

I have an image I'm trying to recreate in pgfplots. We have a `loglogaxis` plot, onto which we would like to add an extra set of axis to show what these values correspond to under a simple transformation. On this site I found a solution on how to add a second axis and I've got the scales ligned up, but I need some suggestion on how the tick marks on the second axis can be transformed.

MWE follows below

1. On the y-axis on the right I'd like to have the number from the axis on the left divided by some number, say 7.5e15. If I manually use `yticks=` to mess with it, those numbers no longer align with the numbers on the x-axis

   (I also need it for the horizontal axis with a different factor, not so important for now)

   BTW: I do not mind typing in the tick labels manually, they should just be place at the same position as on the left y-axis

Bonus questions:

1. In `loglogaxis` how can I get 0.1, 1, 10, etc instead of `10^-1` etc
2. What is the best method for specifying common settings? Here I have to set `width` and `height` in both `loglogaxis` envs

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    xmin=0.4*1e6,
    xmax=1.2*1e9,
    ymin=1e12,
    ymax=5e18,
    width=12cm,
    height=9cm,
    unit vector ratio*=,
    ]
  \end{loglogaxis}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=top,
    xmin=0.4*1e-1,
    xmax=1.2*1e2, 
    ymin=1e-4, 
    ymax=5*1e2,
    width=12cm,
    height=9cm,
    unit vector ratio*=,
    ]
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** For those interested, I used Symbol 1s excellent solution to make this for one if the axis:

```
 \begin{loglogaxis}[
    axis x line*=none,xmajorticks=false,
    axis y line*=right,
    log number format basis/.code 2 args={
      % #1 = base, #2=  exponent   
      \pgfmathparse{(1/9.46)*10^(#2-15)}
      \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3,fixed zerofill,]\pgfmathresult
    },
    ylabel={Some text},
  ]
  \end{loglogaxis}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loglogaxis` environment, in general a log-axis, uses `log number format basis/.code 2 args` to typeset the ticks. That is the key you can play with.

In the following example

- right axis and top axis are treat separately so that one can define different `log number format basis`.
- for right axis, it is currently `$\frac{#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}}{7.5\times10^{15}}$`. You can insert some necessary calculation here. (for example `\pgfmathparse{1/7.5}` and `\pgfmathparse{#2-16}`)
- for top axis, it is currently an if-statement. This shows the possibility to replace 10^{-1}, 10^0, 10^1 by .1, 1, 10 case-by-case. Nevertheless, one might check if `\pgfmathprintnumber` provides what they want.
- `width` and `height` are given to `every axis`.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style={
    xmin=0.4*1e6,
    xmax=1.2*1e9,
    ymin=1e12,
    ymax=5e18,
    width=12cm,
    height=9cm}]
  \begin{loglogaxis}
  \end{loglogaxis}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    axis x line*=none,xmajorticks=false,
    axis y line*=right,
    log number format basis/.code 2 args={
      $\frac{#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}}{7.5\times10^{15}}$
    }
  ]
  \end{loglogaxis}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    axis x line*=top,
    axis y line*=none,ymajorticks=false,
    log number format basis/.code 2 args={
      \ifdim #2 pt=7pt
        \parbox{2cm}{\centering ten \\ to \\ the \\ seventh \\ power}
      \else
        $#1^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}$
      \fi
    }
  ]
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, I'll apply this to the actual image tomorrow